# Increasing voltage from a neon sign transformer

Tags: power, transformer

I am buying a neon sign transformer that is current limiting and iron core for my CO2 laser. I don't know the exact voltage i need but it should be around 15,000 +-1000 volts. Can i "easily" add 1000 volts to it by maybe sending it to a warping of copper coils. I don't want to buy this and then be stuck with a expensive transformer that is to low of voltage.

Comment: Use a Variac? http://www.diyphysics.com/2012/02/18/d-i-y-15-kv-30-ma-floating-output-ac-or-dc-high-voltage-power-supply/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably overdrive the primary of the NST by about 10% or so without running into problems. There are a number of ways to do this.

- Most Variacs (variable autotransformers) are capable of producing about 10% over the input at their maximum setting.
- A 12.6 V filament transformer can be wired as an autotransformer to give a fixed ±12.6V offset (i.e., about ±10% @ 120 VAC nominal). Note that the current rating of this transformer's *secondary* must meet or exceed the *primary* current of the NST.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhW4nZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: so i can wire a "filament transformer" to my neon sign transformer on the output and have it increase by 10% power?

Comment: No, you can increase (or decrease) the *voltage* by 10%.

Comment: yes thats what i meant sorry, so i am ok to buy this transformer and if i find the need to increase the voltage i will just do this?

Comment: The filament transformer (or other low-voltage transformer) would be connected on the primary side of the neon transformer, to adjust the input voltage to that transformer.

Comment: +1 because transformers go by the VA rating, which allows you to swap volts for amps and vice-versa as long as the transformers wattage is not exceeded. Wattage is about 2/3 the VA rating.